# React ( Next) Async / Await Bug on IOS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await, next.js

Friends, help with advice please.
In my App one of the methods to the API using async / await does not return data when opening the project on IOS. Everything is fine on pc and android. At the same time, the method of accessing the API is universal, and if you make a request for other information in another component through it, then everything works.

```
getPopularAnalysis: async(payload, state) => {

      const {data} = await api.get(`/med_test/top`,{
        params: {
          limit: 10,
        }
      })
      alert(data);
      dispatch.categoriesState.setPopularAnalisys(data.slice(0,10));
    }
```

And inside component i use useEffect:

```
 useEffect(() => {
        getPopularAnalysis();
    }, []);
```

Comment: One thing I notice is `setPopularAnalisys` is misspelled (it should be `setPopularAnalysis`), but that doesn't fit the problem description. We can't help you from this end with just the information in the question I'm afraid. You'll need to debug it. (**Don't** use `alert` for debugging. If you can't connect a debugger to your iOS device -- stooopid Apple only supporting Macs! -- create an HTML pane you write to.) See what's in `data` at the point you call `setPopularAnalisys` [sic]. Etc.

Comment: ios - which one? The only flaky thing here is alert.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder https://github.com/google/ios-webkit-debug-proxy . Didn't give it a try yet.

Comment: @EstusFlask - Thanks. I tried one of those about five years ago (possibly that one) and it was sadly very unreliable. But that was five years ago! Fingers crossed.